# C#: is it better to store a reference or to pass it as a parameter?

Tags: c#, performance

I have a parent object that maintains a list of child objects.  Periodically, it iterates through the list of child objects and calls a DoWork method on each one.  Occasionally, the child objects have to refer to the parent object in the DoWork method.  Is it better to store a reference that points back to the parent, using up 4 bytes (right?) times the number of children of memory, or to pass a reference to to the parent as a parameter every time the DoWork() method is called?  What is the overhead if any of passing an extra parameter?  Does MS .NET differ from Mono in this respect?

Comment: Both do abide to CLS. 
Plus these childs inherit from parent??

Comment: The parent and child are not related

Comment: The fact that your child objects need a reference to the parent in order to do their work makes me question your design. What does the parent object have that the children need?

Comment: To (sometimes) access and interact with other child objects, or to notify the parent that it should be removed

Answer (score 1):

when a subroutine is called a stack frame is set up to hold all the input parameters and local variables defined either in the called methods' signature, or as local method-scoped instance fields.  So whether you pass it in as an input parameter or store it as a local field, should not make much difference.

More important, is whether or not the method in question can ever be called from code other than in the parent object, where the parent might not be available... If so, then you need to store the reference as a private field of the child.

Answer (score 1):

Either is about the same overhead i.e. minimal.

However if the children can ever be detached from the parent or reattached to another parent then you have the overhead of managing the stored reference in the child.

Personally I think pass the 'this' from parent each time is the best way.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to avoid the hassle of updating both references

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, it seems a better idea to pass a reference to the parent to the method rather than storing it. The best reasoning that I can come up with is that a method argument will put less pressure on the garbage collector than a stored reference would be.  The reference is not subject to garbage collection because it is automatically cleared when the call stack exits. Plus, if you ever need to pass a different instance,  you can do so easily.

Comment: -1 for not understanding garbage collection... The parent object itself was instantiated somewhere other than in the child object.  What you suggest can only hapen if the only "reachable" reference to the object is the reference stored in the child object, which, clearly is not the case if we are talking about a parent object that arguably must have been instantiated before the child.

Comment: It increases GC pressure because the child objects are larger, and therefore the GC needs to allocate (slightly) more space for each child when compacting heap space during each collection.

Comment: well, even if this were significant (it's only four bytes), that's not what your answer says... You said that the reference " .... is not subject to garbage collection ..." which is not true... Until every reference to the object has been destoyed, the reference stays on the forreachable queue.

Comment: which prevents it from being garbage collected.  Also, if the object was only referenced in the called methods' stack frame, (how can that possibly happen?) than it is precisely the destruction of that reference when the method call exits that would CAUSE the garbage collection to happen.

Comment: First, I said "The reference isn't subject to GC", which is true.  The pointer on the stack frame is not garbage collected, it is erased when the stack frame exits.  The object that it points to is presumably subject to GC, but that isn't what I said. Secondly, no one ever suggested that the children are only referenced from the called method (though that certainly is possible), but as long as we are nitpicking a method exiting never causes GC. GC is triggered by memory pressure (allocation above a certain % of available memory). The loss of the last root pointer just makes an object eligible.